# Check if winapi function is available

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is is possible in c++ to check if a function is available? For example [SetThreadPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority). If it is available, I want to call it, if not I want to simply ignore it, as it is not critical for my application.

Comment: Are you writing for any modern version of Windows? Then `SetThreadPriority` is available; no need to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx) function. The example in the link does exactly this kind of thing: it checks if the `GetNativeSystemInfo` is available and calls it if yes, otherwise it calls the `GetSystemInfo` function.

Comment: A combination of LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() will definitely do the trick. An example of their combined use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810279.aspx

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for [Dynamic Linking Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-functions). If so, then use [LoadLibraryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) then [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(v=VS.85).aspx)

This will allow you skip the DLL load if it is not available